# Writing In-memory IFeatureLayer to Shapefile using ArcObjects (Engine SDK)

Tags: arcobjects, .net

I've been working on this for a little while now, and can not seem to get this thing working.

I've managed to export a geodatabase feature class and shapefile to a shapefile, but what I'm struggling with right now is writing an in-memory feature layer (one that is created based on a selection of features) to a shapefile/geodatabase.

If anyone can help me with a code snippet (doesn't matter the language), or some links to some dark corner of the ESRI docs, I would be much obliged.

**UPDATE**

I used the following code to create the IFeatureLayer:

```
IFeatureSelection featureSelection = (IFeatureSelection)layer;
if (featureSelection.SelectionSet.Count > 0)
{
    IFeatureLayerDefinition2 featDef = (IFeatureLayerDefinition2)featureSelection;
    IFeatureLayer fLayer = featDef.CreateSelectionLayer(
        String.Format( CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            "{0}_Selection", layer.Name ),
        true, "", "" );

    featureSelection.Clear();

    if (fLayer != null)
    {
        _hook.FocusMap.AddLayer( fLayer );
        _hook.ActiveView.Refresh();
    }
}
```

This creates and adds a new layer to the TOC.

What I'm missing now is taking that Feature selection and saving this to a Shapefile (for now).

The code example I've been working with is [from esri code snippets](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/d/00010000028w000000.htm) but I'm getting stuck on the following:

```
IDataset sourceDataset = (IDataset)_layer;

IWorkspace sourceWorkspace;
IPropertySet propertySet = sourceDataset.Workspace.ConnectionProperties;
sourceWorkspace = sourceDataset.Workspace.WorkspaceFactory.Open( propertySet, 0 );

if (sourceDataset.FullName != null)
{
    // HERE - Invalid Cast Exception.
    IWorkspaceName sourceWorkspaceName = (IWorkspaceName)sourceDataset.FullName;
}
```

The full exception is here:

> Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface
>   type 'ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IWorkspaceName'. This operation failed
>   because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface
>   with IID '{FADD975C-E36F-11D1-AA81-00C04FA33A15}' failed due to the
>   following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).

I guess the exception is thrown because the FullName property though is not empty is not compatible because of the type of COM object it is wrapping.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you looking to avoid using the geoprocessor? You could use [FeatureClassToFeatureClass](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/Overview/004700002tq2000000/) and it *should* be able to handle the in-memory feature layer.

Comment: Try code from [here](http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=1170&t=217820#659620).

Comment: @blah238 I am trying to avoid the geoprocessor, though the reasons are for doing so are pride and spite.

Comment: @KirkKuykendall  I might be able to make that work, I'll give it a go tomorrow morning and update the question with the code.  Thanks

Comment: http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IGeoDBDataTransfer2_Interface/0025000003nm000000/

Comment: To get the workspacename of a featurelayer's data source, I would do this: cast IFeatureLayer.Featureclass as IDataset,  then cast the dataset.FullName as IDatasetName, then get IDatasetName.WorkspaceName.

Comment: IMHO the "UPDATE - The Answer" section should be copied and pasted to the Answer section and marked as accepted answer..

Comment: I considered doing that, but I wasn't sure if answering my own question was very sporting.  Someone may have come up with a better solution!  I've made the change ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok Folk, This took some time to get worked out, mainly because it is a part of the ArcObjects API that I haven't worked with often, or frustration clouding pragmatic thought, or an extremely large (misleading) API. I would like to thank [Kirk Kuykendall](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/59/kirk-kuykendall) for some additional resources and ideas on this and other sites.

Here is the solution.  It has been lightly tested but its there for all.

```
public static bool ExportLayerToShapefile(
        string shapePath, 
        string shapeName, 
        ILayer source,
        out IEnumFieldError fieldErrors,
        out IEnumInvalidObject invalidObjects)
{
    IGeoFeatureLayer sourceFeatLayer = (IGeoFeatureLayer)source;
    IFeatureLayer sfeatlayer = (IFeatureLayer)sourceFeatLayer;
    IFeatureClass sfeatClass = sfeatlayer.FeatureClass;
    IDataset sdataset = (IDataset)sfeatClass;
    IDatasetName sdatasetName = (IDatasetName)sdataset.FullName;

    ISelectionSet sSelectionSet = (
        (ITable)source).Select( new QueryFilter(),
        esriSelectionType.esriSelectionTypeHybrid,
        esriSelectionOption.esriSelectionOptionNormal,
        sdataset.Workspace );

    IWorkspaceFactory factory;
    factory = new ShapefileWorkspaceFactory();
    IWorkspace targetWorkspace = factory.OpenFromFile( shapePath, 0 );
    IDataset targetDataset = (IDataset)targetWorkspace;

    IName targetWorkspaceName = targetDataset.FullName;
    IWorkspaceName tWorkspaceName = (IWorkspaceName)targetWorkspaceName;

    IFeatureClassName tFeatClassname = (IFeatureClassName)new FeatureClassName();
    IDatasetName tDatasetName = (IDatasetName)tFeatClassname;
    tDatasetName.Name = shapeName;
    tDatasetName.WorkspaceName = tWorkspaceName;

    IFieldChecker fieldChecker = new FieldChecker();
    IFields sFields = sfeatClass.Fields;
    IFields tFields = null;

    fieldChecker.InputWorkspace = sdataset.Workspace;
    fieldChecker.ValidateWorkspace = targetWorkspace;

    fieldChecker.Validate( sFields, out fieldErrors, out tFields );
    if (fieldErrors != null)
    {
        IFieldError fieldError = null;
        while((fieldError = fieldErrors.Next()) != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(fieldError.FieldError + " : " + fieldError.FieldIndex);
        }
        Console.WriteLine( "[ExportDataViewModel.cs] Errors encountered during field validation" );
    }

    string shapefieldName = sfeatClass.ShapeFieldName;
    int shapeFieldIndex = sfeatClass.FindField( shapefieldName );
    IField shapefield = sFields.get_Field( shapeFieldIndex );
    IGeometryDef geomDef = shapefield.GeometryDef;
    IClone geomDefClone = (IClone)geomDef;
    IClone targetGeomDefClone = geomDefClone.Clone();
    IGeometryDef tGeomDef = (IGeometryDef)targetGeomDefClone;

    IFeatureDataConverter2 featDataConverter = (IFeatureDataConverter2)new FeatureDataConverter();
    invalidObjects = featDataConverter.ConvertFeatureClass(
        sdatasetName,
        null,
        sSelectionSet,
        null,
        tFeatClassname,
        tGeomDef,
        tFields,
        "",
        1000, 0 );

    string fullpath = System.IO.Path.Combine( shapePath, shapeName );
    return System.IO.File.Exists( fullpath );
}
```